# Nautilus / Gnome asks for account to list available SMB shares

Tags: networking, samba, nautilus

I'm currently configuring 3 Samba shares that are all "browseable = yes". Everything works well when I connect on each individual share like :

> \\server\share (Windows) OR smb://server/share (Linux/Debian/Nautilus)

However, from the moment I try to connect directly on the server to list my 3 shares like this :

> \\server OR smb://server

The client asking me for an account before list shares. I don't really understand why and I'm expecting to not being asked for credentials to list the shares. I also put this in the global section of samba config :

> map to guest = bad user

I also tried to list shares with this command :

> root@proxmox:~# smbclient -L nas

But I got this return :

> Password for [WORKGROUP\root]:

It also asking me for an account (which is the current account that execute the command).

I have the feeling that this behavior isn't the same on Windows 10/11. Windows does not ask me for an account to list share. It's pretty weird, why don't all Samba client behave the same way ?

Thank you for your help